# Creating a jsf application with maven without IDE

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, maven

What I want to do is to setup a JSF application without using any IDE to fully understand what is going on.

This is what I have done so far:

I created a directory (D:\Project\MyMavenProject) and added a pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.maxheapsize</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsf2demo</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>jsf2demo Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-b13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-b13</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>jsf2demo</finalName>
  </build>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

and when I say from commandline:

**mvn verify**

I get build error. What am I doing wrong? 
[image]

Here is the link to the image: http://s11.postimage.org/jwr1laf5d/image.png

Comment: Can you post the error you get ? might help.

Comment: Can you post your complete error , it is cut off at the end of image

Comment: You can understand what's going on with or without an IDE. The IDE is just a tool to greatly help you do the things.

Answer (score 1):

```
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/servlet/
```

You repository does not have dependencies for servlet-api or jstl

You can use `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 respository` which contains both jstl and servlet-api versions you are looking for,

```
 <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
     <repository>
      <id>maven2-central</id>
      <name>Maven Central</name>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Also as I see from other post that you don't have your project directories created , 
You can use maven archetypes to create a project without IDE

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.maxheapsize
                       -DartifactId=jsf2demo
                       -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
                       -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
                       -DinteractiveMode=false
```

List of available archetypes can be found here

```
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are specifying only one repository which does not contains all the required depe ndency for your jsf dependency. I think you should try pointing ALSO to the maven central repository. 
It seems that the java repo you are referring does not contain `servlet-api` for example which is required by your jsf pom.

Comment: Do I need to create the directory structure first or am I on the right track?

Comment: I think you can remove the `repositories` tag in your pom and change the value of the version with one given in the following link : http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.sun.faces%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jsf-api%22
The idea is to use default repository and not a custom one which is incomplete (you could still use it in conjunction with maven central repository)
This has nothing to do with jsf there, it is a pure maven problem.

Comment: I am simply trying with:     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0-m10</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency> but still no luck..

Comment: Can you provide me a very simple pom.xml ? I really want to see that maven installs some thing. Then I will try getting back to JSF.

Comment: `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.11</version>
  </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
</project>`

Comment: Thank you. This should simply work in an empty folder right? I copied this to a pom.xml. When I say mvn verify I still get an error. It says failed to collect dependencies, failed to resolve dependencies.

Comment: This won't work in an empty folder. You have to create a project first (using maven archetype for example). Are your project in an empty folder also ? if you want to create a folder structure, have a look at maven archetype feature.